# Query to schedule a match between each team

Tags: sql, oracle

How to fetch Below Output Using SQL Query in Oracle

Scenario:

suppose that in a Table named Team contains  4 records, we need to schedule a match between each team vs opposite team:

```
 Team
    ----
    India
    Pakistan
    Srilanka
    Australia


    Output :
    ----
    India VS Pakistan
    India VS Srilanka
    India VS Australia
    Pakistan VS Srilanka
    Pakistan VS Australia
    Srilanka VS Australia
```

Comment: Join the table with itself using `ON t1.team <> t2.team`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH teams
     AS (SELECT 'India' team
         FROM dual
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Pakistan' team
         FROM dual
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Srilanka' team
         FROM dual
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Australia' team
         FROM dual
         )
SELECT DISTINCT CASE
                  WHEN t1.team >= t2.team THEN t2.team
                  ELSE t1.team
                END  || ' VS '||
                CASE
                  WHEN t1.team >= t2.team THEN t1.team
                  ELSE t2.team
                END Matches
FROM teams t1
       cross join teams t2
WHERE t1.team != t2.team
ORDER BY Matches;
```

Output:

```
Australia VS India
Australia VS Pakistan
Australia VS Srilanka
India VS Pakistan
India VS Srilanka
Pakistan VS Srilanka
```

You may use a different combinations within the `CASE` block

Comment: Needlessly complex. Because your self-join uses the non-equality condition `!=`, your query emits two matches for each pair of teams, which you then have to use complex `CASE` expressions and a `DISTINCT` to remove. Simpler just to use a non-equality condition that produces no duplicates, e.g. `<`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a full join between the same table   where a.team <> b.team

```
select 
       a.team_name || 'VS' || b.team_name
from   
table_team a,  
table_team b
where 
       a.team_id < b.team_id ;
```

if we consider <> then there will be duplicates eg. Ind vs Pak and Pak vs Ind. So string compare less that will always choose on combination

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with a simple `join` . . . but not a `cross join`:

```
with teams as (
      select 'India' as team FROM dual UNION ALL
      select 'Pakistan' as team FROM dual UNION ALL
      select 'Srilanka' as team FROM dual UNION ALL
      select 'Australia' as team FROM dual UNION ALL
     )
select t1.team as team1, team2.team team2
from teams t1 join
     teams t2
     on t1.name < t2.name;
```

This produces one row for each pair.

If you actually wanted to keep the ordering so you get the output as exactly the pairs you specify, you need an ordering column:

```
with teams as (
      select 'India' as team, 1 as n FROM dual UNION ALL
      select 'Pakistan' as team, 2 FROM dual UNION ALL
      select 'Srilanka' as team, 3 FROM dual UNION ALL
      select 'Australia' as team, 4 FROM dual UNION ALL
     )
select t1.team as team1, team2.team team2
from teams t1 join
     teams t2
     on t1.n < t2.n;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH wc 
     AS (SELECT 'India' team 
         FROM   dual 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT 'Pakistan' team 
         FROM   dual 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT 'England' team 
         FROM   dual 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT 'Australia' team 
         FROM   dual) 
SELECT wc1.team, 
       wc2.team 
FROM   wc wc1 
       CROSS JOIN wc wc2 
WHERE  wc1.team != wc2.team 
GROUP  BY wc2.team, 
          wc1.team;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Answering questions is good but this badly formatted answer appears to have the same code as existing answers. Such duplication is not useful. A good answer should provide new insights and new explanations of the topic, not just unexplained code.

Answer (score 0):

Write query like below.

```
SELECT us.user_firstname   AS FirstPlayerFName, 
       us.user_lastname    AS FirstPlayerLName, 
       u.user_firstname    AS SecondPlayerFName, 
       u.user_lastname     AS SecondPlayerLName, 
       tm1.mapped_playerid AS firstPlayerId, 
       tm2.mapped_playerid AS SecondPlayerId 
FROM   tbl_tournamentplayermapping tm1 
       JOIN tbl_tournamentplayermapping tm2 
         ON tm1.mapped_playerid < tm2.mapped_playerid 
       JOIN tbl_user u 
         ON u.user_id = tm1.mapped_playerid 
       JOIN tbl_user us 
         ON us.user_id = tm2.mapped_playerid 
WHERE  tm1.mapped_tournamnetgroup = 'A' 
       AND tm2.mapped_tournamnetgroup = 'A' 
       AND tm1.mapped_scheduleid = tm2.mapped_scheduleid
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do without cross join. try this one.

```
 create table testData(    
    team varchar(10),
   );

insert into testData values ('India');
insert into testData values ('Pakistan');
insert into testData values ('Srilanka');
insert into testData values ('Australia');


select t1.team + ' VS ' + t2.team
  from testData t1,testData t2
 where t1.team < t2.team
 order by t1.team
```

Answer (score -1):

you could try that query :

```
select a.ename "team-a",b.ename "team-b" from #emp a,#emp b where  a.eid != b.eid  order by "team-a"
```